# How to read content from firebase database and pass it to an editview based on the title clicked on the listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my first time posting here so am sorry for any protocol broken.I am working on developing a notepad app in android using firebase which am new to.I have two activities;one with a list view and the other with two edit views(one for title and the other for the content)I was able to push them to the database and populate my listview with the title but i want to be able to get the content back into the editview int the second activity when i click on a title.
My JSON structure:

```
users
  -tsRWgKxh3uX93CVQGWl3u82pWeo2
     -notes
        -KjcNKPVhpKa7mQC09A5
            -notecontent:
            -notetitle:
```

I populated my listview with the.addChildEventListener;

```
 mdbref.child("notes").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            adaptert.add((String) dataSnapshot.child("notetitle").getValue());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            adaptert.remove((String) dataSnapshot.child("notetitle").getValue());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I dont know what is supposed to go in the onclick listview to get the notecontent related to a particular title:

```
            listViewx.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });
```

All help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `title` of your note is listed in your `listViewx` that to know on which particular item the user has clicked, please use the following code:

```
String notetitle = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

Than to check if it's correct, just log the `notetitle` like this:

```
Log.d("TAG", notetitle);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: So, when you click an item from your `listViewx`, what is happening?

Comment: it crashes the application

Comment: there is no error in android studio but when i run the program on the emulator and click on the listview item the application crashes

Comment: If it crashes, you'll have an error for sure. Check the logcat. What is the `error`?

Comment: 05-09 14:14:42.885 19252-19252/com.light.niepaper E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.light.niepaper, PID: 19252
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.light.niepaper/com.light.niepaper.Activities.makebook}: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2695)

Comment: As your logcat says, you need to use `setPersistenceEnabled()` before any usage of FirebaseDatabase instance. Move that method after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`. Should work.

Comment: Thank you.I removed the setPersistanceEnabled() now the second activity opens.

Comment: Perfect. Are you now able to log the `notetitle`?

Comment: I cant see anything after i press ALT+6 to check the log